# Tikz: `\tikztostart`, how to differentiate nodes from coordinates, and obtain coordinate at angle X of node's border

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm curious to know, how can I choose the starting point of a path? I'm trying to produce this kind of pictures when my user draws a path from `A` to `B`:

[image]

However, if I use `(\tikztostart.west)` to specify that the path should start on the west part, then if the users can't anymore do `\path (A.center) to[myC] (B.center)` to force the node to start at center (I guess it evaluates to `A.center.west` which does not exist).

Any idea how to make it work? Also, I'm quite curious: in some libraries like when using `in=40`, they manage to start from the boundary of the node at an arbitrary angle... How is it possible to obtain programmatically this coordinate? **[EDIT** Seems like `\pgfpointshapeborder{}{}` can be useful to do that? TODO: read more in "The basic layer" part of the manual **]**

**BONUS:** why can't I do `\ifnum\y2>0`?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
Problem: need to specify \verb|.west|:
\begin{tikzcd}[
  myC/.style={
    to path={ let \p1=(\tikztostart|-\tikztotarget), \p2=($(\p1)-(\tikztostart)$), \n1={veclen(\x2,\y2)} in arc[start angle=180+90,end angle=90,radius=\n1/2] -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}
  },
  ]
  |[]|                       & |[alias=B,draw,circle]| B\\
  |[alias=A,circle,draw]|A   & |[alias=C,draw,circle]| C
  \arrow[-,from=A.west,to=B.west,myC]
  \arrow[-,from=C.west,to=B.west,myC]
\end{tikzcd}

Problem: can't force start at center.
\begin{tikzcd}[
  myC/.style={
    to path={ (\tikztostart.west) let \p1=(\tikztostart.west|-\tikztotarget.west), \p2=($(\p1)-(\tikztostart.west)$), \n1={veclen(\x2,\y2)} in arc[start angle=180+90,end angle=90,radius=\n1/2] -- (\tikztotarget.west) \tikztonodes}
  },
  ]
  |[]|                       &                           & |[alias=B,draw,circle]| B\\
  |[alias=A,circle,draw]|A   & |[alias=C,draw,circle]| C
  \arrow[-,from=A,to=B,myC]
  % this fails:
  %\arrow[-,from=C.center,to=B,myC]
\end{tikzcd}

Bonus: how to make \verb|\ifnum\y2>0| work?
% \begin{tikzcd}[
%   myC/.style={
%     to path={ let \p1=(\tikztostart|-\tikztotarget), \p2=($(\p1)-(\tikztostart)$), \n1={veclen(\x2,\y2)} in \ifnum\y2>0 \abc>0 arc[start angle=180+90,end angle=90,radius=\n1/2] \else arc[start angle=90,end angle=180+90,radius=\n1/2] \fi -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}
%   },
%   ]
%   |[]|                       & |[alias=B,draw,circle]| B\\
%   |[alias=A,circle,draw]|A   & |[alias=C,draw,circle]| C
%   \arrow[-,from=A.west,to=B.west,myC]
%   \arrow[-,from=B.west,to=C.west,myC]
% \end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**
I managed to do the bonus part using `\pgfextra{\pgfmathparse{\y2>0}}\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1 ... \else ... \fi`:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[
  myC/.style={
    to path={ let \p1=(\tikztostart|-\tikztotarget), \p2=($(\p1)-(\tikztostart)$), \n1={veclen(\x2,\y2)} in \pgfextra{\pgfmathparse{\y2>0}}\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1 arc[start angle=180+90,end angle=90,radius=\n1/2] \else arc[start angle=90,end angle=180+90,radius=\n1/2] \fi -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}
  },
  ]
  |[]|                       & |[alias=B,draw,circle]| B\\
  |[alias=A,circle,draw]|A   & |[alias=C,draw,circle]| C
  \arrow[-,from=A.west,to=B.west,myC]
  \arrow[-,from=B.west,to=C.west,myC]
\end{tikzcd}
```

But the initial question is still open.

**EDIT 2**

After inspecting the source code of tikz, I found out that the `\iftikz@shapeborder` allows to do something like that... but unfortunately I think it does not work with `\tikztotarget` since it does not take any argument... Any idea how to check that information for both the input and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inspecting the source code of tikz, it seems that they test if a node is a shape or not using `\pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}` (but this is documented **nowhere**, so no idea if it's safe to use or not... please let me know!)

So here is how to test that (the style is not yet perfect...). Also, note that `\pgfpointshapeborder` can be used to determine the point on the border of a node that crooses a given line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\ifPgfpointOrCoordinate#1#2#3{%
  \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{%
    #2%
  }{%
    #3%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzcd}[
  myC/.style={
    to path={
      \pgfextra{ %% <- we will use def... so need to "exit" a few seconds pgf
        % Test if tikztostart is a point or a coordinate, and define StartPoint accordingly.
        \ifPgfpointOrCoordinate{\tikztostart}{%
          \def\StartPoint{\tikztostart}%
        }{%
          \def\StartPoint{\tikztostart.west}%
        }}%
      % (\StartPoint) -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}%%
      (\StartPoint) let \p1=(\StartPoint|-\tikztotarget), \p2=($(\p1)-(\StartPoint)$), \n1={veclen(\x2,\y2)} in arc[start angle=180+90,end angle=90,radius=\n1/2] -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}
  },%
  ]
  |[]|                     &                           & |[alias=B,draw,circle]| B \\
  |[alias=A,circle,draw]|A &                           & |[alias=C,draw,circle]| C \\
  |[]|                     & |[alias=D,draw,circle]| D &                           \\
  \arrow[-,from=A,to=B,myC]
  \arrow[-,from=D.center,to=C.south,myC]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**
Here is the full version of the style (preserving arrow tips, and allowing nodes to be arbitrarily placed), let me know if you know a better way to proceed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\ifPgfpointOrNode#1#2#3{%
  \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{%
    #2%
  }{%
    #3%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzcd}[
  myC/.style={
    to path={
      \pgfextra{ %% <- we will use def... so need to "exit" a few seconds pgf
        % Test if tikztostart is a point or a node, and define StartPoint accordingly.
        \ifPgfpointOrNode{\tikztostart}{%
          \def\StartPoint{\tikztostart}%
        }{%
          \def\StartPoint{\tikztostart.west}%
        }%
        % Test if tikztostart is a point or a node, and define StartPoint accordingly.
        \ifPgfpointOrNode{\tikztotarget}{%
          \def\TargetPoint{\tikztotarget}%
        }{%
          \def\TargetPoint{\tikztotarget.west}%
        }%
      }%
      (\StartPoint) % <- the path starts at StartPoint
      %%% Get x coordinate of left-most point
      let \p1=(\StartPoint),
          \p2=(\TargetPoint),
          \n1={min(\x1,\x2)}, % coordinate of the most left part
          \n3={abs(\y1-\y2)/2} % Radius of circle
        in % Warning: no comma after last line before in
        %%%% We go on the left if needed (we check that we do move, otherwise we break the arrows tip if
        %%%% we stay on place
        %%%% First go to the left if needed
        \pgfextra{%
          %% We check if we are moving or not (required to preserve arrow tip direction)
          \pgfmathapproxequalto{\x1}{\n1}%
        }%
        \ifpgfmathcomparison\else -- (\n1,\y1)\fi
        %%%% Version 1:
        \pgfextra{
          \pgfmathparse{
            ifthenelse(\y1<\y2,%
            "arc[start angle=180+90,end angle=90,radius=\n3]",%
            "arc[start angle=90,end angle=180+90,radius=\n3]"%
            )%
          }
        }
        \pgfmathresult
        %%%% Version 2
        % %% We start the arc
        % \pgfextra{% Do math outside of the path construction
        %   \pgfmathparse{\y1<\y2}% \ifnum can only evaluate integers. Use pgfmathparse instead.
        % }%
        % \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1 %
        %   arc[start angle=180+90,end angle=90,radius=\n3]%
        % \else%
        %   arc[start angle=90,end angle=180+90,radius=\n3]%
        % \fi
        %%%% Then go to the right if needed
        \pgfextra{%
          %% We check if we are moving or not (required to preserve arrow tip direction)
          \pgfmathapproxequalto{\x2}{\n1}%
        }%
        \ifpgfmathcomparison\else -- (\TargetPoint)\fi
        \tikztonodes}
  },%
  ]
  |[]|                     &                           & |[alias=B,draw,circle]| B \\
  |[alias=A,circle,draw]|A &                           &                         & |[alias=C,draw,circle]| C \\
  |[]|                     & |[alias=D,draw,circle]| D &                           \\
  \arrow[<-latex,from=A,to=B,myC]
  \arrow[<-,from=C.south,to=D.center,myC]
  \arrow[<->,from=C,to=B.south,myC]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So the problem is neither `node` nor `tikzcd`, it is: given 2 points, say M and N; you want to connect them by a perfect circle in the vertical direction and a straight segment in the horizontal direction ?

Comment: Well it's one of the application I have in mind, yes (assuming it is done via a style), but I've many more other path styles I want to create later. So my question is actually larger: I want to be able to construct many kinds of path styles, and I want to be able to control everything, including the way the paths leave my node. This particular question is on this last point: how can I have different behaviors depending on whether my start and end nodes are points or nodes. That said if you have a quicker way to define this style, I'd be interested, even if it's not my initial question.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple, both the figure and the code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{1.5} 
\path[nodes={circle,draw,minimum size=6mm}]
(0,0)   node (A) {$A$}  
(\a,\a) node (B) {$B$}
(\a,0)  node (C) {$C$}
;
\draw[->] (B.west) --+(180:\a) arc(90:270:\a/2);
\draw[->] (B.west) arc(90:270:\a/2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I want: I want a perfect circle, and even when playing with looseness you won't get one. Also, my question is more general, I'm really curious how to properly define `\tikzstart.west`.

Comment: @tobiasBora  See my edit!

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a style. I really want it to be a style, as I want to use `tikzcd` to use this kind of arrow with something as simple as `\arrow[myC]`. Also here you use a lot some properties on the position of the nodes in the drawing... in the real life I won't have a such simple diagram.

Comment: Honestly, I use plain TikZ to draw all commutative diagrams I met, and see no difficulty. I don't think there is something magical in `tikz-cd`.