# Tikz: check if a node has an anchor, and check the shape of the node

Tags: tikz-pgf

How could I check in tikz (during a path creation) if a node has a given anchor (say `west`)? Notably, I may want to draw different path depending on the type of node that I get, like `\tikztostart.west` if there is a `west` anchor:

```
mystyle/.style={to path={ (\tikztostart.west) -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}}
```

Related: I also want to check if `\tikztostart` is a node (like `A`) or a pgfpoint (like `A.center`)... If you know how to do then you may answer my question there [Tikz: `\tikztostart`, how to differentiate nodes from coordinates, and obtain coordinate at angle X of node's border](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618955/tikz-tikztostart-how-to-differentiate-nodes-from-coordinates-and-obtain-co/618957)

**EDIT**

Note that at least, if a node does not have a given anchor, `A.west` fails gracefully (I think to the point origin). But my initial question is still open.

I also think that one can use [this code](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/247f1f0445a9e996560c9f5a9b3fb03a4184e6ec/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex#L487) to test, namely `\pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@anchor@#1@#2}`, where `#1` seems to be `{\csname pgf@sh@ns@\tikztostart\endcsname}` and `#2` is the name of the anchor, as used [here](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/247f1f0445a9e996560c9f5a9b3fb03a4184e6ec/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex#L531). But this is **not documented**, so it is strange that tikz does not provide a more accessible function...

Comment: Do you know that any TikZ's node ( a generalization of point) has infinitely many anchors, including .west, . 180, .north, .90 ?

Comment: Oh, good to know that there is a `.90` anchor. That said, it's still interesting to know sometimes if a node has a given anchor or not, for instance to do different paths depending on the shape of the node (oh, btw, is it possible to check the shape of a node?).

Comment: All that stuff is in pgfmanual. Please read it before saying something is **not documented**!

Comment: The `.90` is surely yes, but `\pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@anchor#1#2}` is definitely **not documented** (or my pdf's search function is broken...). I've been spending two days on this manual and in the tikz code... and it's 1321 pages, so I don't plan to know it perfectly any time soon. Concerning a function which takes as input a node and outputs the shape, I can't find any (I've been notably reading "Nodes and shapes" (p. 1135), notably "Declaring new shapes" starting page 1143). If I missed it, then could you please point me to it?

Comment: Sometimes we are confusing between reading and understanding. From pgfmanual, page 165, it said that the macro `\tikztotarget` is set to a coordinate. Unlike a node, by definition a coordinate has only one anchor - itself. Therefore, it has no meaning when writing `\tikztostart.west`. I will not discuss more.

Comment: Well this is obviously a first approximation and not the reality, otherwise my code here would not work https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/618993/116348. You can also find in the tikz code that `\tikztostart` is defined differently depending on whether the node is a shape or a coordinate https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/e9c22dc9fe48f975b7fdb32181f03090b3747499/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex#L3102

Comment: `.90` is not an anchor. It triggers computation of a new anchor at that angle on the border on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

After some time I managed to figure it out. I can't find a more "official" solution, I needed to dig into tikz code... Hope it won't break later!

```
\makeatletter
%%% Checks if a function is a point or a node.
%%% Not sure if best solution (needed to dig into source of TeX), but can't find anything better in manual
%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6189553
%%% #1 is the name of the node, for instance \tikztostart in path, or \tikz@fig@name in node.
%%% #2 is code to run if point,
%%% #3 is code to run if node.
\def\ifPgfpointOrNode#1#2#3{%
  \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{%
    #2%
  }{%
    #3%
  }%
}

% This function is needed in the next function (doing \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@anchor@\shapenode{}@#2} fails).
% I guess it has to do with the way macro are expanded...
%%% #1: name of the shape (e.g. "rounded rectangle")
%%% #2: name of the anchor
%%% #3: condition if anchor exists
%%% #4 condition if anchor does not exist
\def\ifAnchorExistsFromShape#1#2#3#4{
  \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@anchor@#1@#2}{%
    #4%
  }{%
    #3%
  }%
}

%%% Check if an anchor exists given a node.
%%% #1: name of the node (e.g. \tikztostart)
%%% #2: name of the anchor
%%% #3: condition if anchor exists
%%% #4 condition if anchor does not exist
\def\ifAnchorExists#1#2#3#4{%
  %%% First we extract the shape of the node:
  \edef\pgf@node@name{#1}%
  \edef\shapenode{\csname pgf@sh@ns@\pgf@node@name\endcsname}%
  \ifAnchorExistsFromShape{\shapenode}{#2}{#3}{#4}
}
\makeatother
```